# Save data into Store from Form Submit success ExtJS

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4, submit

I have a Form (Ext.form.FormPanel) which is basically a login panel with two fields like user_name and password, and a button which does form submit. Now i am able to submit data to my php service which also returns data and i am able to see the data in the action.result (this is actually a UserVO which has fields like user_name, password, user_type, user_id...).

**PFB for the exact data**

```
id
    1

user_name
    "super@super.com"

password
    "cccccccc"

first_name
    "Super"

last_name
    "Super"

user_type
    "Super"

parent_id
    0

_explicitType
    "certification.vo.UserVO"

success
    true
```

Now my question is how is it possible to get grab this result data from action.result, parse it to a Model type and store it in my application so that it is available in the application(Ext.application) for other views to use.

**My User Model class is as below.**

```
Ext.define('Certify.model.UserVO',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id','user_name','password','first_name','last_name','user_type','parent_id','_explicitType']
});
```

**My Application is as below.**

```
Ext.application({
    requires : ['Ext.container.Viewport', 'Ext.form.FormPanel', 'Ext.Window', 'Ext.container.Container', 'Ext.Button', 'Ext.app.Controller'],
    name : 'Certify',
    appFolder : 'app',
    models: ['UserVO'],
    controllers : ['LoginController'],
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout : {
                type : 'vbox',
                align : 'center',
                pack : 'center'
            },
            items : {
                xtype : 'loginview'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**And Also my form submit.**

```
var callData = JSON.stringify(callDataObj);
                    Ext.getCmp('loginForm').getForm().submit({
                        url : url + "login_json/" + callData,
                        method : 'POST',
                        waitTitle : 'Connecting',
                        waitMsg : 'Sending data...',
                        success : function(form, action) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Login Successful!', function(btn, text) {
                                if (btn == 'ok') {
                                    var redirect = './superuser.html';
                                    window.location = redirect;
                                }
                            });
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a valid model you can use it to create a store:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId    : 'myStore',
    model      : 'Certify.model.UserVO',
    [...]
}
```

When your login-form is submitted you can get all the field values with `myForm.getValues()` and use them to add a record to your store. From there on you can use it anywhere in your application.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add